# Switch input date format from MM.DD.YYYY to DD.MM.YYYY format dialogFlow

Tags: javascript, date, dialogflow-es

I am making an reminder app using dialogFlow. I am using `sys.date-time` entity

I have an issue. When I say my bot like

`Remind me bla bla bla in 9.6.2019` (What I supposed is 9th June 2019), but dialogFlow is extracting the date like 6th Sept 2019.

[image: dialogFlow ScreenShot]

Is there any option to switch this input format from MM.DD.YYYY to DD.MM.YYYY in dialogFlow.

DEFAULT TIME ZONE set in dialogFlow is given below.

[image]

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @sid8491 nope, not yet

Comment: I found a solution today.... will put an answer once I am done traveling and get back my laptop.

Comment: @sid8491 Ahh.. Great!. waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you, my first thinking was if I am setting timezone setting to a timezone which considers default date in **DD.MM.YYYY** format instead of **MM.DD.YYYY** format, there should be no issue. But that is not the case in Dialogflow.

We need to set the locale to the correct country which takes DD.MM.YYYY as default time. In my case, I selected English India (en-IN) as in India we consider 03/06/2019 as 3rd June 2019.

So in `Settings -> Language ->` I added `en-IN` as locale under english language. And while calling Dialogflow I passed `en-IN` as language code instead of `en`.

After selecting the correct locale I was getting correct results.

Below is the result when i seleted `en` :

[image: en]

And below is the correct result i got when i selected `en-IN` :

[image: en-IN]

If you are using out of box integration (like Slack or Actions on Google), or not calling DIalogflow yourself then you need to use [localization libraries](https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/) to get the same results.

Hope it helps.

Comment: India we consider 03/06/2019 as 3rd March 2019?? This is confusing. you may be mean 3rd June 2019. right?

Comment: BTW, I tried your solution but its not working. I tried to add en-In as local. see screenshot http://prntscr.com/o6f98o
I am getting the same results before and after adding the locale.

Comment: @QadirHussain yes i meant 3rd June only, sorry for mistake.

Comment: @QadirHussain apart from adding the locale you need to select it as well, if you are using Dialoglfow console then you need to select `en-IN` as shown in screenshot, if you are using any SDK then you need to pass `en-IN` as language code, if you are using direct integration then you need to use Localization libraries.

Comment: Ahh.. Great! This worked. Thank you so much. upvote + accepted as correct answer :)